# If greater than in batch files

Tags: batch-file

I have a very silly issue but unable to figure out what is wrong

I'm doing a basic level number comparison in if statement. script is pasted below. geq-greater than or equal to is working fine but gtr-greater than has a problem. Is there any limitation for numbers in gtr comparison?

```
if 3 gtr 2 (@echo "greater") else (@echo "lesser")
greater

if 3 geq 2 (@echo "greater") else (@echo "lesser")
greater

if 135149772801 gtr 111110000000 (@echo "greater") else (@echo "lesser")
lesser

if 135149772801 geq 111110000000 (@echo "greater") else (@echo "lesser")
greater
```

Comment: Batch arithmetics (and number coparision) is limited to the ±2^31 range

Comment: I recommend putting `@echo off` at the start of your batch file so that you dont have to have the `@` at the front of each command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any limitation for numbers in `gtr` comparison?

Yes, there really *is.*

You're limited to 32-bit signed integers and, if there's overflow, it's set to the maximum value.

Since *both* those numbers, `135149772801` and `111110000000`, are too big, they're both converted to `231 - 1`.

That's why it says the first is not greater (which is subtly different to lesser, by the way) but it *is* greater than or equal to.

More details can be found at the excellent [dostips site](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3758).

Answer (score 1):

A way around the 32-bit limit is to prefix the numeric-string with a goodly number of `0` and then use an alphabetic comparison on the last *n* characters.

Hence

```
set "num1=135149772801"
set "num2=111110000000"
set "zeroes=00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

set "comp1=%zeroes%%num1%"
set "comp2=%zeroes%%num2%"

if "%comp1:~-20%" gtr "%comp2:~-20%" (echo greater) else (echo not greater)
```

where "-20" above means "take the last 20 characters"

Answer (score 0):

A [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) natively supports 32-bit signed integer arithmetic only. If the number goes over 2147483648, it overflows and warp back to negative number. However in `if` statements, the number gets clutter back to `2^31-1`.

```
Code                   | Code Result       | Actual Result
-----------------------+-------------------+-----------------------
2147483647 + 1           2147483648          2147483648
2147483648 + 1          -2147483648          2147483649
```

---

Here is some possible workaround:

- Chopping the number(making the number smaller before comparing)
- Other scripting languages(use `powershell` or `vbs` to compare)

Embedded `Powershell` solution:

```
for /f %p in ('powershell -command if (1 -gt 0^) {write-host greater} else {write-host lesser}') do echo %p
```

This command calls `powershell` to compare, and retrieve the results using a `for` loop.

Comment: They appear to be _clamped_ at the maximum, not wrap-around to negative.

Comment: @TripeHound On my Win7, it does warp back to negative

Comment: Odd. On mine `if 0x81234567 equ 0x7fffffff (echo Equal) else (echo Not equal)` displays `Equal` which suggests clamping.

Comment: I'm not very sure. Maybe batch treats hex and decimal differently. Batch scripting is absurd, by the way.

Comment: Hmm. Can you try `if 2166572391 equ 2147483647 (echo Equal) else (Differ)` which are the same two numbers in decimal -- they're "equal" on my Win 7 (and 10) boxes.

Comment: `if` coerces the values to the respective bounds, independent on whether you use decimal, hexadecimal or octal format, at least since Windows XP up to Windows 7; `set /A` wraps numbers around when a calculation result exceeds either bound; is you state a constant out of range, an error is returned; when you read a number from a variable without surrounding `%%` (or `!!`), it is coerced to the bound. By the way, `2147483647 + 1` does definitely **not** result in `2147483648`, because that number cannot be represented in signed 32-bit (2's complement) format...